# C# - Repositories versus Services in Supplying Custom Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

Good day,

I want to have a clean codes that are basing on the actual enterprise level application. I know how to implement repositories and services but I'm not sure if I'm doing this right.

Suppose, I have a custom class (mostly for json result)

```
public class CustomClass{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

I have a model class (connected to my dbcontext)

```
public class Employees{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my 1st sample repository that supplies the Custom Class

```
// in repository file only
public IEnumerable<CustomClass> SupplyCustomClass(){
     return context.Employees.Select(obj=>new CustomClass{
          Name = obj.Name,
          Age = obj.Age
     }).ToList();
}
```

Here's my 2nd sample, the repository is supplies the first then followed by service.

```
// in repository file (EmployeeRepo)
public IEnumerable<Employees> SupplyEmployeeFirst(){
     return context.Employees.ToList();
}

// in service file
// dependency injection from EmployeeRepo
public IEnumerable<CustomClass> SupplyCustomClassSecond(){
     var customClass = new List<CustomClass>();

     var employees = employeeRepo.SupplyEmployeeFirst();

     foreach(employee in employees){
         customClass.Add(new CustomClass{
             Name = obj.Name,
             Age = obj.Age
         });
     }

     return customClass;
}
```

Both implementation execute the same result. But I want to learn what's the best way in order to follow the rule in enterprise development level.

Comment: The best way is to think about: 1. Why I want repositories and unit of works? 2. Will my application work with another type of storage than relational database? 3. Do I really need to write repositories and so on while the Entity Framework's DbSets and DbContext **already** are repositories and unit of work. And one simple thing that I see in your code: By using Entity Framework's DbSets you can do projection, but when you are using repository you are selecting **all** table columns. And here you should think about: Do I need **all** columns in this query?

Answer (score 0):

From your two approaches, I think the 2nd one is better. The repository should work with Models and not with ViewModels. And as another improvement, you can implement [Unit of Work Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) with Repository pattern.

Answer (score 0):

With the two approaches you have described I would recommend going with a service layer that calls into the repositories (as per your second example). This allows for a clear separation of concerns in that only the repository deals with managing data.

Something important to consider however is that in your examples the second example is wildly inefficient. Your first example will be pulling just 2 columns of data out of the database and constructing your class where as your second example is materialising the entire collection to a list and then you are working with it in memory which places strain on the DB as well as your host process.

This is where clear separation between models and view models can become messy. You can either have the repository spit out the view models to keep maintain performance or you can return `IQueryable` from the repository layer to work with. I personally would recommend having the repository return view models if it is a limited data set you need back but leave all other logic to be done within the service layer. This maintains the repository as the layer that deals directly with your data. In a basic example such as yours its not obvious what work you would then do within the service but there will be plenty of things you wish to do once the data has been pulled out which becomes clear as you flesh out your project. Having this separation allows you to have a clean line between what is fetching your data and the service that may then work with that data to present it, pull in data externally from other API's or other general work that has nothing directly to do with your database.

The short version of the Entity Framework performance consideration is that you want to have it pull out as little data as you can and leave it as an `IQueryable` for as long as possible. Once you run `.ToList()` or iterate over the collection Entity Framework will materialise the result set.